# Why is my break statement being ignored?

Tags: java

In my method under the if statement:

```
if (currentLocationX == 0 && currentLocationY == 4)
```

I have  a break statement that should make the program exit out of the while loop and return true for 'answer' and for the method.  Yet after some testing it seems that after returning true for 'answer', it goes back into the while loop giving the wrong results int the end.  Why is my break statement not doing what it's supposed to? Thank you!
P.S. (this method calls on some other method that were not relevant to mention here)

```
public  boolean solveMaze()
      {
          boolean answer = false;

          int currentLocationX;
          int currentLocationY;
          //push starting location

          pushX(2);
          pushY(1);

          while((isEmptyX() == false) && (isEmptyY() == false))
          {
              printMaze();
              System.out.println();
              currentLocationX = popX();
              currentLocationY = popY();

            //mark current location as visited
               visited(currentLocationX, currentLocationY, maze);
               System.out.println("Current Location: " + currentLocationX + ", " + currentLocationY);

              if (currentLocationX == 0 && currentLocationY == 4)

              {

                  answer = true;
                  break;
              }



             else
               {
                //push all unvisited OPEN neighbor locations into stack
                if (checkEast(currentLocationX, currentLocationY) == 0)
                {
                  pushX(eastX(currentLocationX));
                  pushY(eastY(currentLocationY));
                }

                else;

                if (checkSouth(currentLocationX, currentLocationY)== 0)
                {
                  pushX(southX(currentLocationX));
                  pushY(southY(currentLocationY));
                }
                else;
                if (checkWest(currentLocationX, currentLocationY)== 0)
                {
                  pushX(westX(currentLocationX));
                  pushY(westY(currentLocationY));
                }
                else;
                if (checkNorth(currentLocationX, currentLocationY)== 0)
                {
                  pushX (northX(currentLocationX));
                  pushY(northY(currentLocationY));
                }
                else;     
                }

            }

              return answer;

      }
```

Comment: There's no way the `break` is not working, if you're executing it.  Add a println just before the break and see if it prints.  Also, make sure that whatever is calling the method isn't simply turning around and calling it again.

Comment: Add a breakpoint at 'break' line and debug it to make sure the program reach here,or add print statement here.

Comment: Why do you have semicolons after your `else` statements? What that will do is cause the `else` to have no body. The next `if` is independent. Maybe this is the issue.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss - While it's a strange style, it is legitimate -- indicates that there is no else clause and that the if statements are independent.  A more intuitive style would be an empty `{ }` clause.

Comment: I knew that it was legal; I was not sure that you understood what it was doing. It looked like you were trying to do a standard `else if`, but thought that you had to put in a semicolon. I guess that this was no the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote out the basic logic of your method as

```
public static boolean solveMaze() {

    boolean answer = false;
    int currentLocationX = 0;
    int currentLocationY = 4;

    while (true) {
        if (currentLocationX == 0 && currentLocationY == 4) {
            System.out.println("Hit the break");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Missed the break");
        }
    }

    return answer;
}
```

and if you execute it you get `Hit the break`. So your `solveMaze()` method is fine in terms of breaking out of the loop once it satisfies your if-statement. I would say that if you see your code subsequently going back into the while loop, it must be that `solveMaze()` was called a second time.